# Calling resignFirstResponder doesn't work within overrides firstResponder

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uiresponder

How to focus activated UITextField with UIResponder?

Code below:

```
//  customTextField.swift
import UIKit
class customTextField: UITextField {

override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    if self.tag == 1 {
        self.borderStyle = .Line
        self.superview?.viewWithTag(2)?.resignFirstResponder()
        self.superview?.viewWithTag(3)?.resignFirstResponder()
    } else if self.tag == 2 {
        self.borderStyle = .Line
        self.superview?.viewWithTag(1)?.resignFirstResponder()
        self.superview?.viewWithTag(3)?.resignFirstResponder()            
    } else {
        self.borderStyle = .Line
        self.superview?.viewWithTag(1)?.resignFirstResponder()
        self.superview?.viewWithTag(2)?.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    print("This is called")
    self.borderStyle = .None
    super.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}}
```

I would like to check which textfield is the firstResponder through View's tag. And then if other TextField should be unfocused by resignFirstResponder.

But, the `resignFirstResponder` within the becomefirstResponder's code block isn't even called when I touch a textField in the view.

Comment: Why so much focus on `resignFirstResponder`? Wouldn't simply becoming first responder resign the former responder?

Comment: Thank you for your advise. How can I refer the former responder?

Comment: See answer below: it responds to *Calling resignFirstResponder doesn't work*

Answer (score 8):

**Do not break the superclass: Pass messages along**

In the process of overwriting system messages, like `becomeFirstResponder`, you may inadvertently disable the parent class. The safest, no-op `becomeFirstResponder` is this:

```swift
override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return super.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Omitting `super.becomeFirstResponder()` will compromise `UITextField`.

Also let the original logic *(when to become or not become a responder)* take its course. Always responding `true` or `false` changes the behavior of the parent class, which may have unwanted and unfortunate side effects.

```swift
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        let becomeFirstResponder = super.becomeFirstResponder()
        // Do stuff
        return becomeFirstResponder
    }
```

**Do not replicate the OS**

No need to keep track of the current responder.
Let the OS message you of who is the responder: attempting to do the tracking otherwise may actually not work when the onscreen keyboard gets dismissed without a new field being tapped, and is bound to break. Instead, listen to `resignFirstResponder` in the same manner:

```swift
override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return super.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

**Less code, more flexibility**

Putting both rules together, and using `.RoundedRect` & `.Line` for an explicit redraw (`.None` has no effect), your entire `CustomTextField` could look like so:

```swift
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        let becomeFirstResponder = super.becomeFirstResponder()
        if becomeFirstResponder {
            self.borderStyle = .line
        }
        return becomeFirstResponder
    }

    override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        let resignFirstResponder = super.resignFirstResponder()
        if resignFirstResponder {
            self.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        }
        return resignFirstResponder
    }
}
```

Notice that **no action is taken** if `super.becomeFirstResponder()` or `super.resignFirstResponder()` did not succeed.

---

**Demo**

[image: Animation]

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-34985404) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-34985404).

Comment: Thank you for this. By the way I got failed. Xcode shows me `warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.`

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I think that I found a reason why my project doesn't work like yours. In my storyboard I tied up each label and each textfield by using stack view to make a pair. And then I created three stack views. Each textfield is in each stack view. So I think that in this case your code doesn't work.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/702282/Homepwner-TableView-01.zip) for my project.

Comment: Replace `self.borderStyle = .None` by `self.borderStyle = .RoundedRect`.

Comment: You may need to adjust the layout constraints so that the height of the cell remains constant. There is an odd behavior with `.None`, but `.RoundedRect` works.